# My Function is not executing onClick, and alerting input value

Tags: javascript, html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Input</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
function go (form) {
  var Tid = document.upperform.inputbox.value;
  alert ("You typed: " + Tid);
    //window.location.href = 'http://serverpage=' + Tid + '&tab=0';
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="upperform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Go to this Task ID:
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="" OnBlur="validate(this.form)">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value=" Go " onClick="go(this.form)">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I cannot get this to work. It looks like it should work, but I must have missed something. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a closing bracket

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function go (form) {
  var Tid = document.upperform.inputbox.value;
  alert ("You typed: " + Tid);
    //window.location.href = 'http://serverpage=' + Tid + '&tab=0';
}// <- missing bracket
</script>
```

Comment: That's a brace, not a bracket.

Comment: @LeeTaylor - No. "Brackets are tall punctuation marks used in matched pairs within text." Technically it is a curly bracket, or curly brace, but please, don't be so petty.

Comment: These are brackets (), these are braces {}

Comment: Regardless of name, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @LeeTaylor - You are incorrect. "Braces or Curly brackets { }"

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an ending brace from your function. Other than that, the code works: http://jsfiddle.net/45paz/

```
function go (form) {
  var Tid = document.upperform.inputbox.value;
  alert ("You typed: " + Tid);
}
```